# Pyppeteer: Detect navigation on Page.click method

Tags: python, python-asyncio, google-chrome-headless, pyppeteer

I have the following piece of code which loads a page and follows a link within it, using `asyncio.gather` as recommended in the [documentation for the click method](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.page.Page.click):

```py
import asyncio

import pyppeteer


async def main(selector):
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://example.org")
    result = await asyncio.gather(
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        page.click(selector),
    )
    result = next(filter(None, result))
    if result and isinstance(result, pyppeteer.network_manager.Response):
        print(result.status, result.url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(selector="a"))
```

This works wonders when the `click` method does trigger a navigation event:

```
200 https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved
```

But I'm trying to write generic code that could handle any selector, even those which would not cause a navigation. If I change the selector to "h1" I get the following timeout, because there is no navigation to wait for:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 20, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main(selector="h1"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 12, in main
    page.click(selector),
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/page.py", line 938, in waitForNavigation
    raise error
pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000 ms exceeded.
```

I could not find a way to detect whether or not the `click` event would produce an additional request, in order to avoid the `Page.waitForNavigation` call. Is it possible? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: use `try/except` to catch error.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid waiting for the TimeoutError exception, if there was no navigation to wait for.

Comment: Is the isinstance necessary? What other results are returned?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be filter(lambda x: x is not None, result)?